# Trying to understand MVVM Data keeps resetting

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Goal: When I enter a value in the textbox for Technician Name: I want it to update inside the DataModel and when I click to the NewCallView it will display inside the newcall View and when I click back to the DefaultViewModel it will appear still entered.

Problem: When i change between views the data resets.

I am going to provide my full code in an effort to figure out why my data keeps resetting.  - I am still learning MVVM this is my first crack at it. I would normally make a 1 page application using code-behind. I am finding it hard to link up my Model to my ViewModels, and maybe I am calling (getting/setting)  the properties incorrectly.

With regards to the code behind for each of my Views I did not alter it at all from its creation, I only worked in the Xaml.

Mainwindow codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using callFlow.ViewModels;
using callFlow.Models;

namespace callFlow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void DefaultViewClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new DefaultViewModel();
        }

         private void NewCallClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new NewCallViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Main Window View / wpf

```
<Window x:Class="callFlow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:callFlow"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:callFlow.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:callFlow.Views"  
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Call FLow Management" Height="728" Width="1260">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="defaultViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:DefaultViewModel}">
            <views:DefaultView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="newCallViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:NewCallViewModel}">
            <views:NewCallView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="6" Background=" 
{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBrushKey}}"/>
         <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="6" />
         <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Background="FloralWhite">
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Source="/BofA2.png"  Width="400" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="6" CornerRadius="8 8 8 8"/>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
Grid.RowSpan="6" 
CornerRadius="8 8 8 8"/>
 
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="6">

            <Button Name="loadDefaultView" Content="Home" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="40" 
Margin="5 5 5 5" Click="DefaultViewClicked" >  </Button>
            <Button Name="loadNewCall" Content="New Call" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="40" 
Margin="5 0 5 0 " Click="NewCallClicked" ></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="6" Content=" 
  {Binding}">
            
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>


</Window>
```

Views/DefaultView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="callFlow.Views.DefaultView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:callFlow.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:callFlow.ViewModels"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:callFlow.Models"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="FloralWhite">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="0 10 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Text="Call Flow Management" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="0 5 0 0">        
         <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Technician Name: " 
 FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="134"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="5 5 5 0">
            <TextBox Name="techName" Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName,Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  BorderBrush="#FF4A5780" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
            </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextUpdate" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,0,0,0" 
Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModels/DefaultViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using callFlow.Models;


namespace callFlow.ViewModels
 {
    public class DefaultViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        


        public DefaultViewModel() { }

        private ObservableCollection<DataModel> model = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
        private DataModel _SelectedModel;

   

        public DataModel SelectedModel
        {
            get { return _SelectedModel ?? (_SelectedModel = new DataModel()); }
            set { _SelectedModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public void changeSelectedModel(DataModel newSelectedModel)
        {
            SelectedModel.TechName = newSelectedModel.TechName;

        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string techName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(techName));
        }


    }
}
```

Views\NewCallView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="callFlow.Views.NewCallView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:callFlow.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:callFlow.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="#FFFDFDFD">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="techNameSet" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,52,0,0" 
 Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="114"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

NewCallViewModel.cs

```
namespace callFlow.ViewModels
{
    class NewCallViewModel
    {
//It's empty, my view is calling SelectedModel.TechName from DataViewModel which works when I update the DataModel Directly          
    }
}
```

Last but not least!!!!

Models/DataModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;



namespace callFlow.Models
{
    public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        private string techName;

        public DataModel()
        {
        }

        public string TechName
        {
            get { return techName; }
            set { techName = value;  OnPropertyChanged(); } 

        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string techName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(techName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You either need to persist and re read your data or retain a reference to it. Instead you new up your viewmodel every time. DataContext = new DefaultViewModel();

Comment: @Andy how would i persist the data, do you have a msdn doc or article i could reference?

Comment: A database is a common choice, but you could serialise to disk and deserialise back into objects.

Comment: @Andy is there a way without using a database?  I mean its not that I am against it but for this project it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can serialise and deserialise model data. As i suggested. Our game suite works that way.

Comment: @Andy I am unsure how that is done, could you reference a syntax sheet i can review?

Comment: you don't need database, 
the problem with your solution is that you are creating the view model (data context) "each time" you switch between pages. use local variables in your main window and set them once.